# Binding Typed List to an SQL Server query?

Tags: c#, list, data-binding

OK, so I have an SQLS db that I want to query using some JOIN commands. I know how to do that, but here's the bit I don't quite know how to do yet:

How do I bind the results of said query to a single typed list so that changes to the list can be easily written to the database?

Reason I want to do this is that I'm using a control (Phillip Piper's ObjectListView's TreeListView) that binds itself to a list, so I need to get data from that control back into the DB in a sensible manner that ideally doesn't involve tons of boilerplate code.

The idea being that the user can play with the values in the Treelistview (which automatically updates the list, this bit works quite happily), then the user can hit save and then something (a dataadapter I'm guessing? I'm new to C# and SQLS and still fuzzy on the whole binding thing) updates *just the changed values* in the relevant tables.

Sorry if this seems like basic stuff, but putting 'bind query results to a typed list' into google returns loads of stuff that's irrelevant, or stuff that I'm not advanced enough to understand yet. I think I need this in pure newbie layman's terms :P

Comment: OK, I figured out that I didn't need to go via a list in the end, I've managed to bind the TreeListView directly to a datatable, so that nulls the original question. However, this has led to a different, but related question: the problem is that the DataAdapter won't update joined tables. What's my easiest way around this one? If I need to start a new question then just let me know. Code is as follows:[br]

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't want to let me post any code here...anyone any idea why? 'Add Comment' just does nothing when I paste code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I canned the joined DataTable idea and just read the data straight into a List of my objects with a DataReader. So this whole question is now pretty redundant for me. Hopefully someone else will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is Microsoft's main ORM offering, though [Linq2Sql](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) is great and easy to use. [NHibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to SQL
Have a look at PLINQO, it will automate most of it for you
[www.plinqo.com](http://www.plinqo.com)